# Как решить проблему с отображением цвета

Tags: javascript, html, css, opencart

Есть рабочий [проект](http://horeca.itf-studio.com.ua/) на OpenCart, в карточке товара есть опция цвет, она подтягивается с админки, но проблема в том что подтягивается и отображается кодом. Что прописать и как, что бы цвет отображался цветом скажем в виде квадрата 25x25 пикселей. Думаю на js, но не могу сообразить как это сделать? Небольшой скрипт, который будет обрабатывать аргументы c `#`.

[image: карточка товара]

Код в карточке товара:

```
<?php if ($attribute_groups) { ?>
<div id="tab-attribute" class="tab-content no-margin table-responsive">
    <table class="attribute table">
        <?php foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) { ?>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><?php echo $attribute_group['name']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $attribute['text']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно работать вот так

```
<?php if ($attribute_groups) { ?>
    <div id="tab-attribute" class="tab-content no-margin table-responsive">
        <table class="attribute table">
            <?php foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) { ?>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $attribute_group['name']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                            $tbl_text = $attribute['text'];
                            $pos = strpos($tbl_text, '#');
                            if ($pos === 0) {
                                echo '<div style="background-color:'.$tbl_text.';width:25px;height:25px;margin:0px auto;"></div>';
                            } else {
                                echo $tbl_text;
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: где-то знак препинания что ли не стоит, редактор ругается

Comment: поставил, но теперь пропал цвет даже кодом.. че делать?

Comment: обновил. в строке `echo '<div sty...` поставить в конце `;`

Comment: давайте подробнее, что происходит? текст текстом остался, а где должен быть цвет - пустое место?

Comment: исчез и текст и не отображается цвет картинкой

Comment: вы имеете ввиду те строки где должен быть текст, или ВСЯ таблица теперь пустая?

Comment: да вся пустая теперь

Comment: давайте скриншот. пустая только правая часть или левая тоже?

Comment: в чате написал какая ошибка сейчас

Answer (score 1):

Вместо вывода значение свойства, выводите небольшой стилизованный блок( размеры, позиция), а в коде пропишите так

```
  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></td>
      <td>
        <div class='item_color' style="background:<?php echo $attribute['text'];?>"><div>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Соответственно напиши проверку на ключ, и если это цвет, то выводите этот блок, js тут не нужен

Comment: этот код дописать в php код?

Comment: @zorro, да, там же где прописывается остальная таблица

Comment: а как писать ключ проверки?